# kendo ui form update cancel button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I am trying to a simple kendo ui form with 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons. I am using the Kendo.Observable to bind the data to the form.
The functionality I am trying to achieve is, if the 'Save' button is clicked, the form data will be saved. Else, if 'Cancel' is clicked the form will come back to read-only mode with the previous data that was present. To do this, I am first saving the model data in a 'originalvalue' property on click of Update button. If 'Cancel' is clicked, the 'fields' model data is restored to the 'originalvalue'. But the issue is that the , 'originalvalue' does not contain the original value. It gets updated when the user is editing during 'Save'.
The question is - how do I retain the original model data so that it can be refreshed on cancel?
Please find below the code. Appreciate your help, thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = kendo.observable ({

        updated: false,
        originalvalue: {},

        update: function(e) {
            var original = this.get("fields");
            this.set("originalvalue", original);
            this.set("updated", true);
        },

        save: function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             if (validator.validate()) {
                    // make an ajax call to save this data
                    this.set("updated", false);
             } 

        },

        cancel: function(e) {
            var original = this.get("originalvalue");
            validator.destroy();
            this.set("fields", original);
            this.set("updated", false);

        },

        fields: {}
    });

    viewModel.set("fields", formArray);     
    kendo.bind($("#outerForm"), viewModel);

    // prepare the validator
    var validator = $("#outerForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make the exact thing on a form I am currently developing. I am using a DataSource object for the data so I had to use cancelChange().

The thing I did there:
1. I made a Datasource with a schema:

```
 ... schema: {
model: {id: "id"}}
...
```

2. I got the object I was editing with the mapped id:

```
clientDataSource.cancelChanges(clientDataSource.get(this.get("contactID")));
```

where the ContactID is created in a setData function where I have passed the ID:

```
 this.set("contactID", contactID);
```

As I may have notices and understood, you have another problem here where you arent using a DataSource but rather data for fields?
The problem here is that your originalValue is inside the Observable object and it is referenced to the variable **original** and thus it has observable properties. You should have the variable **originalValue** defined outside the observable object:

```
var originalValue;

var viewModel = kendo.observable ({ ...
```

And you should send the **formArray** also to that variable so you will have the defaults load before even the observable object is loaded such as:

```
originalValue =   formArray;  
viewModel.set("fields", formArray);
```

So when you need to cancel it you should have:

```
cancel: function(e) {
            var original = originalValue;
            validator.destroy();
            this.set("fields", original);
            this.set("updated", false);

        },
```

I havent tested it but it should provide you some guidance on how to solve that problem.