# Triggering OnCancel event of kendo upload on click of button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

[image]

I want to Cancel the file uploading on click of cancel button.

means I want to trigger the **onCancel(e)** event on click of my **cancel button**

My code is,

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
  .Name("files")
   .Multiple(false)
   .Async(a => a
    .Save("UploadArtifactFile", "PP", new { TeacherEvalID = ViewBag.TeacherEvalID, ObservationID = ViewBag.ObservationID, Accountid = ViewBag.AccountID })
    .AutoUpload(false)
    .RemoveField("")
     )
    .Events(events => events
    .Success("onSuccess")
    .Select("onSelect")
    .Error("onUploadError")
    .Upload("onUpload")
     .Cancel("onCancel")
     .Remove("onRemove")
      )

   On cancel event is work as expected,  

function onCancel(e) {
        //Array with information about the uploaded files
        var files = e.files;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

I want to do the same thing for Cancel Button and on click of cancel button i have write code as,

```
function setNewArtifact() {
        var upload = $("#files").data("kendoUpload");
        //detach events and prepare for safe removal
        //upload.destroy();

        $(".k-upload-files.k-reset").find("li").remove();
        $('#lblArtifactFileName').val("");
        $('#lblArtifactFileName').hide();
        //hdnArtifactUploadIsAddOrEdit :1 for new artifact (Add)
        $('#hdnArtifactUploadIsAddOrEdit').val("1");
        $('#txtArtifactDescription').val("");
        $('#lblArtifactFileName').hide();
        $('#btnModifyArtifact').css("display", "none");
        $('.k-upload-selected').css("display", "none");

        //on click of cancel hide the uploading and uploaded status
        $(".k-dropzone").find("strong").css("display","none");
        $(".k-upload-status.k-upload-status-total").find("span").css("display","none");

        $.extend(upload.options.localization, {
            headerStatusUploading: "",
            headerStatusUploaded: ""
        });

    }
```

There is any way to do this?

Please help...

Comment: Try first. If you get any error, then ask here. To search for ways and tutorials, www.google.com is there.

Comment: I have tried a lot.and searched for manually triggering event an click of button. but I didn't get any answer.

Comment: I have write the code as  <button type="button" onclick="setNewArtifact();" class="k-button.k-button-bare.k-upload-action">Cancel</button>    function setNewArtifact() {  //on click of cancel hide the uploading and uploaded status
        $(".k-dropzone").find("strong").css("display","none");
        $(".k-upload-status.k-upload-status-total").find("span").css("display","none");

        $.extend(upload.options.localization, {
            headerStatusUploading: "",
            headerStatusUploaded: ""
        });}

Comment: Have a look at this.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565570/kendo-ui-form-update-cancel-button

Comment: I have also write the Cancel event for file uploading. Its work perfectly when i click on that circle button which is kendo upload remove button. But i want to trigger that same event on click of cancel button also. Please see the attached image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger upload cancel event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
      saveUrl: "save",
      removeUrl: "remove",
      autoUpload: true
    },
    cancel: function(e) {
      alert("cancel");
    }
  });

  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    $("#files").data("kendoUpload").trigger("cancel"); 
  });
});
```

```html
<input name="files" id="files" type="file" />
<button id="button">Cancel</button>
```