# Triggering remove event of kendo upload on click of button is not working

Tags: file-upload, kendo-ui

I want to remove selected file of kendo upload control on click event of another button and I followed the below link 
[Triggering OnCancel event of kendo upload on click of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29160004/triggering-oncancel-event-of-kendo-upload-on-click-of-button) the remove event fired but not clear the file below is my code. please can any one help me what i am doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#files").kendoUpload({
            "multiple": false,
            select: function (event) {
                console.log(event);
                var notAllowed = false;
                $.each(event.files, function (index, value) {
                    if ((value.extension).toLowerCase() !== '.jpg') {
                        alert("not allowed! only jpg files!");
                        notAllowed = true;
                    }
                    else if (value.size > 3000000) {
                        alert("file size must less than 3MB ");
                        notAllowed = true;
                    }
                    if (event.files.length > 1) {
                        alert("Please select single file.");
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                });

                var breakPoint = 0;
                if (notAllowed == true) event.preventDefault();
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function (event) {

                    var mapImage = event.target.result;
                    $("#sigimage").attr('src', mapImage);
                    document.getElementById("sigimage").style.display = 'block';


                }
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(event.files[0].rawFile);

            },
                remove: function (e) {
                    alert("remove");
                    e.preventDefault();
                },

        });
        $("#closewindow").click(function (e) {
            $("#files").data("kendoUpload").trigger("remove");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code for removing the file inside your click function.

`$(".k-delete").parent().click();`

Please visit the [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/wepevebera/1/edit) here for a working example

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom function like this:

```
function remove(){
    $(".k-upload-files").remove();
    $(".k-upload-status").remove();
    $(".k-upload.k-header").addClass("k-upload-empty");
    $(".k-upload-button").removeClass("k-state-focused");
};
```

It will delete trigger delete of uploaded files.